# MIDlet as singleton

Tags: java-me, singleton, design-patterns, midlet

Is it safe to implement a `MIDlet` class as a singleton? That is, after all, the Display class is acting *like* a singleton for each and every midlet so is the midlet itself a singleton by behaviour so that implementing it as such wouldn't break something?

In other words, it is not possible to have two instances of an app running, is it? I mean, the AMS wouldn't allow it, would it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Singleton classes have protected constructor, and this will cause a problem because the AMS needs the MIDlet class constructor to be public not protected nor private.

Comment: Thanks! I know that. the question was not implementation, but behaviour. Thanks!